# Append only the first item of an Array inside Json Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to parse some data from JSON but I have an understanding issue.
So this is the JSON

```
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "images" : [
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/14680504_1200113096725648_1728625782476314570_n.jpg?oh=a20884ad66bef170b7afa9d4f109abf1&oe=585F830B",
          "width" : 349,
          "height" : 557
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p320x320\/14680504_1200113096725648_1728625782476314570_n.jpg?oh=effc78bc088150bc762a79d7b0cfad6c&oe=5860B857",
          "width" : 320,
          "height" : 510
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p180x540\/14680504_1200113096725648_1728625782476314570_n.jpg?oh=e014f2b98eb8152dbfd84b6fdfefc25b&oe=58913E1C",
          "width" : 338,
          "height" : 540
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/14680504_1200113096725648_1728625782476314570_n.jpg?oh=ce0430df1e0e605b2b33542634b70adb&oe=58A3A2B0",
          "width" : 130,
          "height" : 207
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p75x225\/14680504_1200113096725648_1728625782476314570_n.jpg?oh=18ed8685d773104637f8a747b21783af&oe=58689107",
          "width" : 140,
          "height" : 225
        }
      ],
      "id" : "1200113096725648"
    },
    {
      "images" : [
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/14732411_1196819920388299_7949002046479842067_n.jpg?oh=7b7a61f956594f0015dea746640f3e33&oe=589B36EA",
          "width" : 294,
          "height" : 171
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/14732411_1196819920388299_7949002046479842067_n.jpg?oh=fe74c57b606ef817aed805707fe6fe6d&oe=58A96851",
          "width" : 223,
          "height" : 130
        }
      ],
      "id" : "1196819920388299"
    },
    {
      "images" : [
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-8\/14753242_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_o.jpg",
          "width" : 1920,
          "height" : 1200
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-8\/p960x960\/14753242_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_o.jpg",
          "width" : 1536,
          "height" : 960
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-8\/p720x720\/14753242_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_o.jpg",
          "width" : 1152,
          "height" : 720
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/14650295_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_n.jpg?oh=19248c58a8a11a4506b364aa44a7dc4a&oe=58A4E3F0",
          "width" : 960,
          "height" : 600
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-0\/p480x480\/14753242_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_o.jpg",
          "width" : 768,
          "height" : 480
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p320x320\/14650295_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_n.jpg?oh=672575780d6ec2c46c7fc0b25421941c&oe=589800AC",
          "width" : 512,
          "height" : 320
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-0\/p180x540\/14753242_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_o.jpg",
          "width" : 864,
          "height" : 540
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/14650295_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_n.jpg?oh=f6441f7dde33aec00785f7f96dea31b5&oe=58A1D94B",
          "width" : 208,
          "height" : 130
        },
        {
          "source" : "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p75x225\/14650295_1194616067275351_4639120157874462599_n.jpg?oh=bbe7ab23b13269a062bfcfa0afcce8e1&oe=589A7EFC",
          "width" : 360,
          "height" : 225
        }
      ],
      "id" : "1194616067275351"
    }
  ],
  "paging" : {
    "cursors" : {
      "after" : "MTE5NDYxNjA2NzI3NTM1MQZDZD",
      "before" : "MTIwMDExMzA5NjcyNTY0OAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I get it with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

```
Alamofire.request("https://graph.facebook.com/\(eventId1)/photos", method: .get, parameters: ["fields": "images", "access_token": "token"])
            .responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
                if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                    print(swiftyJsonVar)
```

My question is, how can I take the FIRST `source` of each `images` array inside that JSON and append it to an empty array???
I've tried several ways but it always takes the 5 sources inside the first `images`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            if let images = swiftyJsonVar["data"].array {
                for i in 0...images.count-1 {
                let source = images[i]["images"][0]["source"].string

                            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
                                if let url  = NSURL(string: source!),

                                    let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
                                {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                        self.sliderPinakas.append(UIImage(data:data as Data)!)

                                        self.makeSlider()
                                    });
                                }

                            }
                }
            } else {
                        self.sliderPinakas.append(UIImage(named: "noimageinside")!)

                        self.makeSlider()

            }
```

It was easier than I thought.
Just had to put all the data into an array and then loop inside it.